# Getting pen pressures as an input in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes, grease-pencil, draw-mode

Is there anyway to get the pen pressures 0.0 - 1.0 as an input in Geometry Nodes? Can’t find a way to do it yet.

As I want to let user draw 3D line similar to grease pencil. I use curve to draw as well but it’s not be able to capture those pressure sensitivity during each stroke.

Comment: Such feature is currently not available. However you could use pen pressure in Weight Paint or Color Paint mode and you can use the resulted weight / color information instead of the pen pressure. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you @RumenBelev I’ve update my question to be more specific and more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a Curve with the radius affected by the pen pressure - activate **Use Pressure** for the Draw Tool:

[image]

When you add a Geometry Node to that Curve it transfers the Curve Radius and you can simply use **Curve To Mesh** node to see the effect:

[image]

To control the Curve Radius you can use the **Radius** and **Set Curve Radius** nodes plus **Math** or **Float Curve** nodes between them:

[image]

Comment: Let me try this, I think this might be able to capture those pen inputs this way.